# How to download CSV file in swift iOS app

Tags: ios, swift

I want to download a csv file at a particular URL and then access it later. I'm new to downloading with URL's in iOS apps so can someone point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+download+file+url